# Publish code from private svn to git/github

Tags: git, svn, github

I currently develop an android-application I want to publish to github. As all my code is in a private svn, I'm looking for a possibility to do achieve the following:

The app contains some assets I'm not allowed to publish but which are required by the actual applications I publish in playstore. The application contains some sample data which is used to show users how to build their own assets.

Therefor I need a way to publish only parts of the application to github but keep the full application in our local svn. I only need the trunk to be published.

I thought about something like this (very abstract):

- Create a .gitignore file with the assets
- Create a git repository on my server using git svn

  - add github as remote
- Add a commit hook to the svn which does

  - git svn clone $LASTREVISION -s https://my.local.svn/app
  - git remote add myGithubRemote git://github.com/foo/bar.git
  - git push myGithubRemote master

But frankly speaking, I'm not sure, if this really works or if there will be any problem.

I would appreciate any helpful ideas or comments :)

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

your approach is good, use .gitignore to "hide" content.

I would also look on submodules - use it for storing your private data.
place all your private data in a private folder, set this folder to be submodule and the location of the submodule is in your private network so no one will be able to fetch it.

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: i dont think this resolves my problem but thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

## Suggestion

It sounds like you're using git not for versioning, but for releasing parts of the codebase for others to build upon.

Rather than using git-svn, it's probably better to create a separate repo for this and either copy-paste the snapshots or create the git repo inside of the svn repo.

Reason is git-svn is more for sharing commit history with svn, rather than for publishing part of the repo.

You can create an SVN hook and have it auto publish part of the git repo, but using real git commands instead of git svn commands.

Remember to setup your .gitattributes and .gitignore files first before creating the repo though, as git's history is best thought of as immutable.